# Protractor / WebDriverJS Return element values as an array of objects

Tags: javascript, jasmine, promise, protractor, webdriverjs

I'm from Java+WebDriver background and new to Protractor, WebdriverJS and Jasmine. In the displayed image I'm trying to hover the mouse over all bubbles and get the tool tip values (city, sold, connected) and assign them to an array as objects and return it to the calling function. Can anyone please tell me how to create an array of objects in this situation? I'm trying to assert it from my spec file.

When I call this function the ***return arr;*** runs before the rest of the code. Seems it is due to the Asynchronous behavior.

```
this.getSalesVolumeDistribution = function() {
var arr = [];
var icons = element.all(by.css('#map-container svg>circle'));
icons.map(function(elm) {
        browser.actions().mouseMove(elm).perform();
        var toolTipCity = element(by
            .css('#map-container g.highcharts-tooltip tspan:nth-of-type(2)'));
        var toolTipUnitsSold = element(by
            .css('#map-container g.highcharts-tooltip tspan:nth-of-type(3)'));
        var toolTipUnitsConnceted = element(by
            .css('#map-container g.highcharts-tooltip tspan:nth-of-type(4)'));

        toolTipCity.getText().then(function(text) {
            var cityVal = text.replace('City: ', '').replace(',', '');
            console.log(text.replace('City: ', '').replace(',', ''));
            var soldVal = toolTipUnitsSold.getText().then(function(text) {
                return text.replace('Units Sold: ', '').replace(',', '');
            });
            var connVal = toolTipUnitsConnceted.getText().then(function(text) {
                return text.replace('Units Connected: ', '');
            });

            arr.push({
                city: cityVal,
                sold: soldVal,
                conn: connVal
            });

            });
    });
return arr;
};
```

[image]

Comment: What exactly doesn't work here? What's the error/what's wrong with the output?

Comment: When I call this function the ***return arr;*** runs before the rest of the code. Seems it is due to the Asynchronous behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should return the result of [`map()`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.map) which *would be a promise resolving into an array of objects*:

```
this.getSalesVolumeDistribution = function() {
    var icons = element.all(by.css('#map-container svg>circle'));

    // CHANGE WAS MADE HERE v
    return icons.map(function(elm) {
        browser.actions().mouseMove(elm).perform();
        var toolTipCity = element(by
            .css('#map-container g.highcharts-tooltip tspan:nth-of-type(2)')).getText();
        var toolTipUnitsSold = element(by
            .css('#map-container g.highcharts-tooltip tspan:nth-of-type(3)')).getText();
        var toolTipUnitsConnceted = element(by
            .css('#map-container g.highcharts-tooltip tspan:nth-of-type(4)')).getText();

        // CHANGE WAS MADE HERE v
        return protractor.promise.all([toolTipCity, toolTipUnitsSold, toolTipUnitsConnceted]).then(function(tooltips) {
            var cityVal = tooltips[0].replace('City: ', '').replace(',', '');
            var soldVal = tooltips[1].replace('Units Sold: ', '').replace(',', '');
            var connVal = tooltips[2].replace('Units Connected: ', '');

            // CHANGE WAS MADE HERE v
            return {
                city: cityVal,
                sold: soldVal,
                conn: connVal
            };
        });
    });
};
```

Note how I've put the `return`s here (marked with comments). And notice the `protractor.promise.all()` that helped to resolve multiple promises for the tooltip texts.

Then, if you need to assert the result of the function, put it into `expect()` - it would resolve the promise implicitly and then make the assertion, e.g.:

```
expect(myPageObject.getSalesVolumeDistribution()).toEqual([
    {city: 'El Paso', sold: '344', conn: '321'},
    {city: 'New York', sold: '500', conn: '600'}
]);
```

Comment: Made multiple edits and done editing at this moment - make sure you are trying the latest version of the code.

Comment: this worked perfectly for me. I learnt lot of new things from your solution. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 1):

The map function in protractor will allow you to return an array of values: http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.map

So instead of pushing onto array just do:
return
{
     city: cityVal,
     sold: soldVal,
     conn: connVal
}